# $_POST does not echo a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, submit

The page is basically a form for adding new products to the products table in the database. The form must include image upload as well. The function is supposed to echo the query before inserting any data to the database. However, every time I press on the submit button it doesn't show the query, and the form just resets itself. I tried different solutions, yet they don't work. I changed the form action to a new php page, and still not working. I also tried to use two different browsers, and tried display error codes. Is there something messing in the code?

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
        <?php
        include("../includes/db.php");

        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Insert a Product</title>
        <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.3/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <form name="submit" action="insert_product.php"method="POST"enctype="multipart/from-data">

    <table align="center" width="800">


    <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="8"><h4>Insert New Post Here</h4></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Title:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pro_name" /></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td align="right"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
    <td><input type="FILE" name="product_image" id="product_image"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Color:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Color"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Location:</b></td>
    <td>
    <select name="location">
    <option>Select a Location</option>
    <?php

    $get_location = "select * from location";

    $run_location = mysqli_query($conn, $get_location);

    while ($row_location=mysqli_fetch_array($run_location)){
    $Loc_name = $row_location['Loc_name'];
    $location_id = $row_location['location_id'];
    echo "<option value='$location_id'>$Loc_name</option>";

    }
    ?>

    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Supplier:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pro_supplier"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Cost:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cost"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pro_keywords"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Product Description:</b></td>
    <td><textarea name="Pro_desc" cols="20" rows="10"/></textarea></td>
    </tr>




    <tr align="center">

    <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert Product Now"/></td>
    </tr>

    </form>


    </body>





    </html>

    <?php






    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['product_image'])){


    $pro_name = $_POST['pro_name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $Color = $_POST['Color'];
    $cost = $_POST['cost'];
    $pro_desc = $_POST['pro_desc'];
    $pro_keywords = $_POST['pro_keywords'];

    $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_imgtmp = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']));



    echo $insert_product =
    "insert into products
    (pro_name, price, Color, cost, Pro_desc, pro_keywords, product_image)
    VALUES
    ('$pro_name','$price','$Color','$cost','$pro_desc','$pro_keywords','$product_image')";


    if ($conn->query($insert_product) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert_product . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    }



    ?>
```

Comment: `action="insert_product.php"method="POST"enctype="multipart/from` Need spaces my friend Spaces

Comment: I did add spaces to my original code. Still not working.

Comment: Well seen @HankyPanky! This small details are often hard to see.

Comment: you're echoing the result of an assignment operation, so all you'll see is `true`. To see your query, assign the sql to `$insert_product` and then `echo $insert_product`

Comment: also, look into prepared statements & bind placeholders, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: also to note, that because your insert is AFTER your query/display, any new insert will not be shown on the result page.  You may want to move your check/insert code to above the display table so that if it inserts, you see the result with the inserted values.

Comment: It's a *damn typo* `from-data` which should read as `enctype="multipart/form-data` - form form form and not `from` and error reporting would have thrown you something about it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ***undefined index blah blah blah***

Comment: having added `else { echo "it broke..."; }` for your `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['product_image'])){...}` would have shown you "it broke".

Comment: @RobGudgeon That wouldn't cause their code to fail. It's a typo, as I stated a few comments above. **IF** that's their "real" code.

Comment: Plus, you have a conflict here `<form name="submit"` and your submit button is named the same `<input type="submit" name="submit"`, remove the name attribute for the `<form>`. Btw, did anyone go over their code **entirely** before posting/commenting?

Comment: good catch @Fred-ii-, I saw the db include failure error and didn't look beyond that.

Comment: @Dave It's those *tiny little details* that will put a damper on one's day lol

Comment: @Dave I'm finding even more syntax errors in their code, after using a *finer toothed comb*.

Comment: @Abdul I've made a few edits to my answer since I originally posted and you'll have to go over it and reload it. You're also not using some of the attributes from your form in your query, so that's unknown. check for errors as outlined in my answer. That's the best I can offer at this time.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** After going through the code again and with an even *finer tooth comb*, have noticed a few more errors. Consult my **Edit:** also below.

Firstly, have you a typo here, being `from` instead of `form`:

```
enctype="multipart/from-data"
                   ^^^^
```

which should have read as:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
                   ^^^^
```

Then your `<form name="submit">` and submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit"` both bear the same name attribute of `submit`.

- Remove `name="submit"` from `<form>`, **that's a conflict.**

Having added an `else{ echo "Something went wrong..."; }` to your conditional statement would have fallen into it from the get go.

Error reporting would have also helped you out here.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Now, whatever is inside `db.php` is unknown to us. Since you're using the MySQLi API to query with, the connection for it must be the same one, `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or PDO, should that be the case.

- Different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

> *"However, every time I press on the submit button it doesn't show the query"*

Your conditional statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) 
 && isset($_FILES['product_image']))
```

is checking if both the submit is pressed `AND-&&` the file is set.

You may want to use an `||` (OR) here instead, if that file is ever "not set/empty".

For user provided input, use a conditional `!empty()`, it's better.

- **So, make sure that both conditions are met.**

That could be changed to:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ){

    // do something in here

 if( !empty($_FILES['product_image']) ){

    // do something else in here
 }
 else{
    // you can do stuff here too for an empty file condition
    }

 }
```

---

**HTML stickler:**

`<!DOCTYPE>` isn't a proper doctype declaration, and should read as `<!DOCTYPE html>` as a minimum HTML5-supported method.

Otherwise, consult the following for all valid types:

- https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

---

**Footnotes:**

Your present code is open to an [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

## Edit:

Upon looking further at your code:

`<textarea name="Pro_desc"` and `$_POST['pro_desc']`. Notice the uppercase `P` in the name attribute?

Those POST arrays are case-sensitive and again; error reporting would have thrown you something about it, being `undefined index pro_desc`.

It should read as:

- `$_POST['Pro_desc']`

*Pro tip:* Use the same letter-case convention throughout your code. You can quickly get lost into using mixed case variables and they are case-sensitive. My preference has always been to use all lowercase letters for variables, arrays, etc.

- Be careful with that.

Plus, if you're attempting to insert the uploaded file in your database as binary, you will need to escape that data with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and setting your column as BLOB or LONGBLOB, depending on the size of the file.

Also make sure that there isn't an file upload constraint size restriction.

Rerences:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)
- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I did the best I could here. The rest lies in the OP's hands.

Comment: How did i know this is @Fred's answer after reading just the first line?

Comment: @HankyPanky *You know my style* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1st create spaces at the form code:

```
<form name="submit" action="insert_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/from-data">
```

Then on your PHP code do not echo the operation i.e.

**Change this**

```
 echo $insert_product =
    "insert into products
    (pro_name, price, Color, cost, Pro_desc, pro_keywords, product_image)
    VALUES
    ('$pro_name','$price','$Color','$cost','$pro_desc','$pro_keywords','$product_image')";
```

**to this**

```
$insert_product =
        "insert into products
        (pro_name, price, Color, cost, Pro_desc, pro_keywords, product_image)
        VALUES
        ('$pro_name','$price','$Color','$cost','$pro_desc','$pro_keywords','$product_image')";
echo $insert_product;
```

Comment: he'll still want to echo this afterwards, as he's trying to debug the SQL statement

Comment: I have added the echo now  @RobGudgeon